# Prove that $f$ is one-one if $g\circ f$ is one-one.

Tags: functions

Given $X,Y,Z\neq \emptyset$ 
Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and let $g:Y \rightarrow Z$  
I know that since $g\circ f$ is one-one therefore $g\circ f(x_1)=g\circ f(x_2)$ when $x_1=x_2$  
In other words, $g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2))$ when $x_1=x_2$  
I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: To be explicit, one should always put the question in the post body. It's OK for it to be in the title too, but not only there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: ''I know that since gof is one-one therefore gof(x1)=gof(x2) when x1=x2.''

No, it's vice versa: $g\circ f(x_1) = g\circ f(x_2)$ implies $x_1=x_2$.

Let $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. Since $g$ is a function, $g\circ f(x_1) = g\circ f(x_2)$.
Since $g\circ f$ is one-to-one, $x_1=x_2$. Hence, $f$ is one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that f is not one-one then there exist $x_1,x_2$ such that

$f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ and $x_1 \neq x_2$

$f(x_1)=f(x_2) \Rightarrow g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2))$

However, since $gof$ is one-one

$x_1 \neq x_2 \Rightarrow g(f(x_1))\neq g(f(x_2))$

contradiction !! hence f must be one-one